# How to clear stack in masm32 coprocessor (FPU)?

Tags: masm32, fpu

Doing some operations in **masm32** `FPU`. But I'm not able to clear the stack of FPU e.g. ST(0)-ST(7) afterwards. Is there any instruction for stack clearing. Can you suggest anything?

P.S.
Suppose to clear stack for further calculation.

Comment: IF you want to restart anew, `FINIT` / `FNINIT` should be enough. Depends if you want to keep control, status, or anything else...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FINIT` which initializes the FPU and tags the data registers ST(0)-ST(7) as empty (it does not clear their contents though)