# Get value of all FPU registers, even "empty" ones

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I am writing an extension for a software and certain important values are in the FPU registers. Some of those registers are marked as empty, but they still contain important values. Because those registers are marked as empty, everytime I try to use something like fxch in order to get the value in, let's say, `st(6)` to `st(0)`, so I can store it in memory, it automatically gets changed to NaN.

Is there any way to change the status from empty to valid or to read those registers in any way? I know debuggers can see them, but I need to do it programatically with either C++ or x86 ASM.

Edit:
As some of you might know, there is a TAG register marking some FPU registers as "empty". This happens for example, when FINNIT is called, however the actual value bits are not changed by that, it's basically just telling the system, that those spots in the FPU stacks are now free. I want to read those values from the FPU stack, but because they are marked as "empty" or you could say "invalid" it doesn't work with the normal instructions. I realize, that it's not a common use-case, but I need those registers because of reverse engineering.

To be specific: how can I print all FPU registers on Windows, 32 bit, even if they are marked as "empty"?

Comment: You can't do this with C++, though maybe you can with x86 ASM, though I wouldn't know how reliable that would be as it will depend on the operating system, the details of your threading environment, what sort of threads or fibers you have, etc, and perhaps even the particular type of x86 CPU you have.

Comment: What is an "empty" register exactly? How does one "mark" a register as being empty? I've never heard of this before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840658/how-to-clear-stack-in-masm32-coprocessor-fpu like this for example. More effective than popping several times and the actual values remain in the register.

Comment: In simulation you can have 3 and 4 state bits (0,1,x or 0,1,x,z) and perhaps more, but in the real world the bits are 0 or 1...not 0,1,empty.

Comment: @RemyLebeau . I'm assuming what he meant is that he wants to access the value in the FPU stack slots that are marked empty. Each slot is associated with an FPU register st(0) to st(7) and can either be empty or used. That is at least how I interpreted the question.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the case. I thought those were like the first bits in the data registers tbh, but now I know they are separate status registers. I tried to make my question clear, although I had to keep the headline short. I also don't really understand the downvotes. What I am asking: how can I get every FPU register into (cpu memory?) (RAM memory?) so that I can for example printf it, even if the status registers of those FPU registers are marked as "empty".

Comment: @user3273154: It's a very specialised question, it can be difficult to ask in a generic fashion.  So you'd be better off being very, very precise.  Be exact in terms of CPU. The type of register.  Do you want the CPU cache as well?  Even then, there are only a small number of engineers who will be able to answer it.

Comment: @Arafangion Well he only needs one, but I would hope there are at least several thousand engineers here who can answer this question. I will, as soon as it is reopened from its mystifying closure.

Comment: EJP: I agree, I think the closing was a bit harsh.

Comment: @user3273154: After a bit of googling, it seems that you could be referring to the x87 FPU registers (8 of them), or you could be referring to "all" of the floating point registers, (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138382/which-registers-do-x86-x64-processors-use-for-floating-point-math ).  I did not vote to close, btw - just voted to reopen. :)

Comment: Have you considered using the [FSAVE](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FSAVE:FNSAVE.html) instruction to dump the entire FPU state to memory print out the data you want and then use [FRSTOR](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FRSTOR.html) to restore the state saved by _FSAVE_ . You need to restore the original data because FSAVE has the side effect of resetting the entire FPU state after saving the state to memory.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I used FSAVE and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Michael Petch suggested I was able to save all registers using FSAVE. Then I only had to access the memory, where I saved the registers and convert them from the extended precision representation to a normal 32bit float.